# ScrollViewer holds the child element when panning in UWP

Tags: uwp, panel, panning

Scrolling is not happen when i panning the custom control. I have a custom control it's derived from Panel, I placed this control inside the `ScrollViewer`. And I have set the `ManipulationMode` for my custom control as "All". And triggered the `ManipulationDelta` and change the `VericalOffset` and `HorizontalOffSet` by using `ChangeView` method in `ScrollViewer`. The VerticalOffSet and HorizontalOffSet is set for my panel based on my panning, but in view there is no change, the `ScrollViewer` holds the Panel.

I have tired lot of ways but the problem is not resolved.Triggered the `ViewChanging` and set the `VerticalOffSet` and `HorizontalOffSet`. Triggered the `ManipulationDelta` for `ScrollViewer` and set the `VerticalOffSet` and `HorizontalOffSet`. Triggered the `ManipulationStaring`, `ManipulationDelta` and `ManipulationCompleted`, set the `VerticalOffSet` and `HorizontalOffSet` for both CustomPanel and `ScrollViewer`.

```
<Grid>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" 

                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <local:CustomPanel x:Name="customPanel" Height="800" Width="900"
                               ManipulationMode="All"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
private void OnContainerOnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (scrollViewer!= null)
        {
            if (scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode == ScrollMode.Disabled && scrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode == ScrollMode.Disabled)
                return;
            var verticalOffset = e.Delta.Translation.Y;
            var horizontalOffset = e.Delta.Translation.X;
           this.scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, VerticalOffset - verticalOffset, null, true);
         this.scrollViewer.ChangeView(HorizontalOffset - horizontalOffset, null, null, true););

            e.Handled = true;
        }

   }
```

Note : I have some fixed rows in our custom grid(CustomPanel), while scrolling without set the `ManipulationMode` the fixed rows are flicker, so only i triggered the `ManipulationDelta`.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

> Scrolling is not happen when i panning the custom control.

If I understand it correctly, I think the problem is the values of `VerticalOffset - verticalOffset` and `HorizontalOffset - horizontalOffset` don't change.

And manipulation usually cooperates with RenderTransform. If you want to panning your UIElement, you need to give a `TranslateTransform` to your `CustomPanel`.

I made a demo and modified your codes like below:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private TranslateTransform dragTranslation;
    private double HorizontalOffset;
    private double VerticalOffset;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        customPanel.ManipulationDelta += CustomPanel_ManipulationDelta;
        dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
        //give a translate transform to customPanel.
        customPanel.RenderTransform = this.dragTranslation;
    }

    private void CustomPanel_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (scrollViewer != null)
        {
            if (scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode == ScrollMode.Disabled && scrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode == ScrollMode.Disabled)
                return;
            var verticalOffset = e.Delta.Translation.Y;
            var horizontalOffset = e.Delta.Translation.X;
            this.dragTranslation.X += horizontalOffset;
            this.dragTranslation.Y += verticalOffset;
            HorizontalOffset += horizontalOffset;//Here dynamically increase the HorizontalOffset;
            VerticalOffset += verticalOffset;//Here dynamically increase the VerticalOffset;
            this.scrollViewer.ChangeView(null,VerticalOffset, null, true);
            this.scrollViewer.ChangeView(HorizontalOffset, null, null, true);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  >
        <local:CustomPanel x:Name="customPanel" Width="800" Height="800" 
                           ManipulationMode="All" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock> Panning Me</TextBlock>
        </local:CustomPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

As you can see everytime `CustomPanel_ManipulationDelta` triggered, I increase the `HorizontalOffset` and `VerticalOffset`.

Here is the Outcome:

[image]

Comment: Elvis - Thank you for your suggestion, I have checked your suggestion on my side in Mobile device, but its not works. Is there is any solution to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Maybe share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem, and I'll try to fix that demo for you.